# Change default landing page of a laravel website

Tags: php, laravel

I know i is a very common question, but i am purely new to laravel and i know very little about laravel thats's why i am asking it.

So point is that when a user enters http://dytube.cric4fun.com/ he must be automatically redirected to the http://dytube.cric4fun.com/login

So, how i do this, in past in simple non-laravel based we used .htaccess and in laravel how we will do it.

Comment: Please put your web.php content here as well.

Comment: It contains lot of data, how all that can be pasted here!

Comment: I have uploaded web.php on link below: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PlXx82_X0LRNcb6CULUE2PqWZjIzi2wT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You can change your home directory route in web.php file like this:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return redirect()->route('login');
});
```

This way, if the user is logged in, he/she will be automatically redirected to home page and anywhere you have chosen for redirection after successful login.

Comment: not working in my case.